# pure-ftpd auth blocked by SELinux

Tags: ftp, selinux, pureftpd

First, my setup. I'm using CentOS 6.4 and I installed pure-ftpd (plus the SELinux module) from the EPEL repositories :

```
> rpm -q pure-ftpd pure-ftpd-selinux
pure-ftpd-1.0.30-1.el6.x86_64
pure-ftpd-selinux-1.0.30-1.el6.x86_64
```

After struggling with getting this to work with SELinux properly, I tried `setsebool`'ing a few things :

```
allow_ftpd_full_access --> on
ftp_home_dir --> on
ftpd_use_passive_mode --> on
```

The context in which pure-ftpd is running (as `root.root`) :

```
system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 25196 ? Ss    0:00 pure-ftpd (SERVER)
```

---

Now, the problem. For some unknown reason, SELinux denies login attempts without logging at all to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. pure-ftpd logs this (in `-d -d` mode) :

```
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [INFO] New connection from <my_ip>
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 220-Local time is now 17:53. Server port: 21.
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [TLS]
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 234 AUTH TLS OK.
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [INFO] SSL/TLS: Enabled TLSv1/SSLv3 with DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 256 secret bits cipher
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] Command [user] [admin]
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 331 User admin OK. Password required
Jul 10 17:53:39 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] Command [pass] [<*>]
Jul 10 17:53:42 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 530 Login authentication failed
Jul 10 17:53:42 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Jul 10 17:53:42 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [INFO] Logout.
Jul 10 17:53:42 <hostname> pure-ftpd: (?@<my_ip>) [DEBUG] 530 Logout.
```

When I `setenforce 0`, the login suddenly works perfectly fine. When I then `setenforce 1` again and reconnect, it won't let me login.

Again: **auditd doesn't log anything** and the pure-ftpd logs are useless. `/var/log/secure` also stays empty and `tail -f /var/log/*` only shows the syslog messages I pasted above.

For completeness, he's my `pure-ftpd.conf`:

```
# Core
Daemonize                   yes
#PassivePortRange           35000 35999
ProhibitDotFilesWrite       no
ProhibitDotFilesRead        no

# Security
#ChrootEveryone             yes
NoAnonymous                 yes
UnixAuthentication          yes
MinUID                      499
UseFtpUsers                 no
#TLS                        2
VerboseLog                  yes
VerboseLog                  yes

# Logging
SyslogFacility              local5
AltLog                      clf:/var/log/pureftpd.log

# Performance
DontResolve                 yes
MaxIdleTime                 15
LimitRecursion              10000 8
MaxLoad                     4
MaxDiskUsage                99

# Customer happy
CustomerProof               yes
NoTruncate                  yes
#AllowUserFXP               yes
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try running `ausearch -ts today -m avc -m user_avc -m selinux_err` and see if this shows you anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of SELinux policies are flagged `dontaudit` so that they [do not leave messages in the audit log](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/11673.html). This is usually because they are policies that would just spam the log with useless entries, but sometimes developers `dontaudit` a denial rather than fixing the underlying problem. The policy you're hitting is almost certainly among these, since you aren't seeing any messages being logged in `audit.log`.

You can temporarily disable `dontaudit` by running:

```
semodule -DB
```

After you've discovered the cause of the problem, re-enable `dontaudit` with:

```
semodule -B
```

To build your policy once you've generated it, run:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the default policy is built around PAM auth while I put it in Unix auth mode. `allow ftpd_t shadow_t:file { read open };` did the job :)